# g++ can't find this method even though it's included

Tags: c++, installation, g++, makefile, linker-errors

I am using FANN (http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/download/). Both headers are available in the archive that you can download there (I hope I don't create too much trouble for you).

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: johannsebastian
 *
 * Created on November 26, 2013, 8:50 PM
 */

#include "../FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/include/doublefann.h"
#include "../FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/include/fann_cpp.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace FANN;

/*
 * 
 */

//Remember: fann_type is double!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    neural_net * N = new neural_net;
    const unsigned int myLayerArray[4] = {1,2,2,1};
    const unsigned int numLayers = 4;
    N->create_standard(3,1,2,1);
    cout<<"Easy!";
    return 0;
}
```

g++ says

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/bachnet
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/bachnet build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `FANN::neural_net::destroy()':
/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet/../FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/include/fann_cpp.h:915: undefined reference to `fann_get_user_data'
/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet/../FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/include/fann_cpp.h:919: undefined reference to `fann_destroy'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `FANN::neural_net::create_standard_array(unsigned int, unsigned int const*)':
/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet/../FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/include/fann_cpp.h:979: undefined reference to `fann_create_standard_array'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/bachnet] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johannsebastian/Desktop/heatmap3d/BACHnet/BACHnet'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 773ms)
```

Can you help me fix this? I think I might have some basic compiler config wrong or something.

Comment: Where's `fann_get_user_data` and the other listed functions suppose to be? If they're part of an external library you probably have to link it in which I don't see you doing in the link command.

Comment: It's the linker that is complaining You need to link to the library.

Comment: Did you build and install the library using CMake? After doing this, add required FANN libraries to your project makefile.

Comment: @Duck How? FANN only told me to include those two files.

Comment: @AlexFarber How? The header comments say that I only have to include those like that. Can you tell me how to do the CMake thing, or link to a guide?

Comment: @Duck Can you show me how to link to the library for the linker?

Comment: @greatwolf It's in doublefann, which is referenced by fann_cpp. How do I add these to the linker?

Comment: @SimonKuang `doublefann.h` has the declarations but where's the implementation for it?

Comment: @greatwolf They're in `fann.h`, which `doublefann.h` includes.

Comment: It's not in there otherwise you wouldn't be getting those unresolved linking errors. The function implementation shouldn't be in the headers anyway because you risk multiple definitions if you include it in more than one translation unit.

Comment: @Simon Kuang From the docs it looks like the default install puts the libraries in /usr/local/lib.  Look in there (or below) for something like libfannfloat or libfanndouble and such.  When you find where the libs are you have to add `-L<path to libs> and -l<lib name> to the end of your g++ compile lines.  See 
klm123's answer.

Comment: @Duck (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273275/g-ld-configuration-to-add-a-library-and-code-modifications-therefor) I'll try `g++ -lFANN`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I fixed it by adding the dynamic library to Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The compiler has compiled your code. The includes are really work. (But you don't have to specify full path there, just the name of the header, if the library is installed correctly).
2. This is the linker (`ld`) who can't find the method.
3. The linker problems about whether you have library with the method definition and give it to the linker (in its options) when you call it.
4. You use make file, so you have to specify options (something like `-lFANN`) and path to the library there (like `-L/path/path/path`. The path you also can specified in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` system variable, then you don't need `-L` option). Also you have to install (compile) the library itself before to use it. You have installation guide [here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/installing-fann/).

The guide works for me:

Download the FANN-2.2.0-Source.

Install it with cmake:

```
[08:42:24]~/Downloads$ cd FANN-2.2.0-Source/
[08:42:27]~/Downloads/FANN-2.2.0-Source$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  README.txt  bin     datasets    src
COPYING.txt VS2010      cmake       examples
[08:42:27]~/Downloads/FANN-2.2.0-Source$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/local/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/local/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /<...>g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /<...>g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- FANN is used as APPLICATION_NAME
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/ikulakov/Downloads/FANN-2.2.0-Source
[08:43:57]~/Downloads/FANN-2.2.0-Source$ make
Scanning dependencies of target doublefann
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/doublefann.dir/doublefann.c.o
Linking C shared library libdoublefann.dylib
[ 25%] Built target doublefann
Scanning dependencies of target fann
[ 50%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/fann.dir/floatfann.c.o
Linking C shared library libfann.dylib
[ 50%] Built target fann
Scanning dependencies of target fixedfann
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/fixedfann.dir/fixedfann.c.o
Linking C shared library libfixedfann.dylib
[ 75%] Built target fixedfann
Scanning dependencies of target floatfann
[100%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/floatfann.dir/floatfann.c.o
Linking C shared library libfloatfann.dylib
[100%] Built target floatfann
[08:44:02]~/Downloads/FANN-2.2.0-Source$ sudo make install
```

Comment: @SimonKuang, what you did exactly? It works for me (see the answer).

Comment: Alright. I got CMake to work and I `sudo make install`ed it: everything worked. How do I change my code now? (and/or my linker stuff)

Comment: @SimonKuang, have you checked examples like mentioned in "When all else fails"?? You have Makefile example there. The key option I think is -lfann.

Comment: Yes. That was the example in my question, except the C++ version.

Comment: I have installed everything I ought to. How should I change my code now? Apparently the "when all else fails" does not work.

Comment: @SimonKuang, you don't give enough information. Explain in the question what exactly You did with your code and Makefile to make them follow the given examples. And how do you exactly compile. I can't repeat everything for you one more time like I have installed your package just to say you that the installation does work.

Comment: @SimonKuang, better even make a new question. Apparently current one is not valid any more.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, not the *Compiler*, but the **Linker** fails to find the function.

The compiler is what you satisfy with including the files containing the declarations of the functions you use, and specifying the directory for the included files.

The linker wants to see the actual library containing the compiled definition of the code.

You probably have to specify `-lfann` on the linker command line (for the exact name to use after `-l`, refer to what the library is actually called - if it is called libfann.so, use above parameter).

In case the library is installed in the default directories, thish should be enough; otherwise you might also need the `-L` parameter pointing to the path containing the library (and the library would have to be compiled first, of course).